# Does Izuku control his One-For-All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I've searched everywhere online and can't find any recent pages but does Izuku control his One-For-All? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean 100%, then the answer is no.

**At the end of the second season of the anime:**

> He could use up to 5% of its power. He used it to fight the hero killer Stain. (Ep. 14-18)

**As of chapter 156 of the manga:**

> In the fight against Chisaki, he could control up to 20% of his power.

Answer (score 2):

At first, no. It is for this that he continues to injure himself so badly.

In chapter 41 after his match in the sports festival, it becomes an immediate need that he learn to control his power because Recovery Girl declares that she won't heal him anymore. In fact, this is one of the main problems in the beginning of the series, the fact that he can't control his power. Most of the second season is dedicated to his progress at controlling his power.

Later in season 2, Midoriya has an internship with Gran Torino and comes to learn that he shouldn't focus so much on trying to activate the power, as much as make the power completely part of all his actions. Always active, but at the level which he can control. Which at that point, is 5%.

So, yes he is slowly learning to control his power. That is a main struggle he faces within the story.

Answer (score 0):

He learned to control One for All but it's only 5%. He learned to control it when he's interning for Gran Torino. He got the idea from when he made a mistake in heating the taiyaki (because the taiyaki was not rotating inside the microwave) that they will had for breakfast.

> He figured that he should use One for All not just when he needs it to
>   and what body part he will use it to but he needs to activate it to
>   his whole body *all the time*.

Reference for this are episodes 14 and 15.